# how to get unicode for font awesome icon 5?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, plugins

I used font awesomeson icon picker plugin to select the icons, but I want unicode with this icon.

used plugin:

https://itsjavi.com/fontawesome-iconpicker/

do you have any idea to get unicode by icon name? from plugin iconpicker I will get icon name but I want unicode not name

How can I do that?

Comment: @allart how to integrate to this plugin?

Comment: @allart when I select icons from iconpicker I want to get unicode .

Comment: But how do you select them in the first place?

Comment: @Allart do you have any idea to get unicode by icon name? from plugin icon picker I will get icon name. But I want unicode not name

Comment: Ahh I see now, sorry I think I dont know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download and parse the [icons.json](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/metadata/icons.json) file from the public repo of FontAwesome. Then, you upload it into your application, and make an utility which searchs for the unicode of the selected icon.

I include in this answer a short example of how you could make it work.

```js
function getIconUnicode(iconName) {
  const fontAwesomeSource = {
    "500px": { "unicode": "f26e" },
    "accessible-icon": { "unicode": "f368" }
    ...
  };

  // if iconName is in the format of "fas fa-address-book"
  // it should be parsed in order to reflect the name present in the JSON

  const selectedIcon = iconName.split(' ')[1].split('-').splice(1).join('-');

  const unicodeValue = fontAwesomeSource[selectedIcon].unicode;

  return unicodeValue;
}

// example taken from the GitHub repo of the plugin
$('.my').on('iconpickerSelected', function(event){
  console.log(getIconUnicode(event.iconpickerValue));
});
```

Comment: when to trigger with that iconpicker plugin?

Comment: You should trigger the function i wrote, every time the plugin returns to you the icon name, for example on the `iconpickerSelected` event

Comment: event.iconpickerValue returns 'fas fa-address-book' but inside function getIconUnicode(iconName) variable 'iconName' not used anywhere. how it is linked?

Comment: yes sorry, it should be in selected icon; I update my code

Comment: ```
function  getIconUnicode(iname) {
        
        let  unicode = $.getJSON("{{asset('js/icons.json')}}", 
                            function (data) {
                               let val =  data[iname].unicode;
                               return val;
                });
        return unicode;
        
    }

```

I want to return data

Comment: @nithisha I cannot understand what you are missing